# StackExchange.Redis | TTL -2 | Issue

Tags: c#, azure, stackexchange.redis, ttl

What does TTL Status Code -2 mean? I am trying to set expiration for my Redis Key while calling StringSet(key, value, expirationTimeSpan).

I have set expiry by 1 minute. When I run TTL MyKey, it counts down 59, 58, 57,.. suddenly it drops to -2.

I am using Azure Redis Cache Service Basic 256mb and 2.5gb scale.

What was the problem? Is it something to do with active\ passive expiry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](https://redis.io/commands/ttl):

> Starting with Redis 2.8 the return value in case of error changed:
>
> - The command returns -2 if the key does not exist.
> - The command returns -1 if the key exists but has no associated expire.

So: it got deleted, presumably.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Redis Key was indeed deleted by other parallel thread. Hence, that explained behavior of **-2**. I thought it was due to failed-promise-azure-redis-cache with basic-or-low-tiers. Your answer really helped.